# How to wait until all tasks are finished before running code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

I am trying to write a multi threading search and then display all the results once the tasks have finished running but currently I don't understand how to process the results once all the tasks are complete

My code is as follows:

```
    private async void DoSearchAsync()
    {
        var productResults = await SearchProductsAsync(CoreCache.AllProducts);
        var brochureResults = await SearchBrochuresAsync(CoreCache.AllBrochures);

        _searchResults.AddRange(productResults); 
        _searchResults.AddRange(brochureResults);

        ResultsCount = _searchResults.Count;
    }
```

Where `_searchResults` is a `List<SearchResult>`

My understanding is that it will do both of the awaits simultaneously and then add the products to the search results.  However when I call this in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchText)
    {
        SearchHelper helper = new SearchHelper(searchText);
        helper.DoSearchAsync();

        return View(helper);
    }
```

It is displaying the page before the searches are complete so no results are showing up.  How do I make it wait for the results to finish before showing the page?

I've had a look into `Tasks.Wait` but don't know how to apply it to the above as it expects an array of tasks

```
    private Task<List<SearchResult>> SearchProductsAsync(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        return Task<List<SearchResult>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetProducts(products));
    }

    private Task<List<SearchResult>> SearchBrochuresAsync(IEnumerable<Assets> brochures)
    {
        return Task<List<SearchResult>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetBrochures(brochures));
    }
```

Comment: can you post the method signature for SearchProductsAsync and SearchBrochureAsync

Comment: @Baldy methods added as requested

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly but Task<List<SearchResult>> is not an array of tasks, it's a single task that returns a list List<SearchResult>, you can probably call the Result property after waiting to get the results you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EduardoWada Yes each task will return a list of search results and then when all tasks have completed I want to add the ranges of each list to `_searchResults`

Comment: You can call wait on all tasks one by one, then access their results if you need to sincronize there should be no problem on awaiting them in any order

Comment: You almost never want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` on ASP.NET. What is `GetProducts` doing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every time you call `Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` inside an ASP.NET controller, you grab a thread from `ThreadPool`. That thread could be otherwise serving another incoming HTTP request. So, your're really hurting your web app scalability. This may be a serious issue, depending on how many concurrent HTTP requests your web app is expected to receive.

Are you OK with that? If so, the code could look like this:

```
private async Task DoSearchAsync()
{
    var productResults = SearchProductsAsync(CoreCache.AllProducts);
    var brochureResults = SearchBrochuresAsync(CoreCache.AllBrochures);

    await Task.WhenAll(productResults, brochureResults);

    _searchResults.AddRange(productResults.Result); 
    _searchResults.AddRange(brochureResultsbrochure.Results);

    ResultsCount = _searchResults.Count;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchText)
{
    SearchHelper helper = new SearchHelper(searchText);

    await helper.DoSearchAsync();

    return View(helper);
}
```

Note I changed `async void` to `async Task` for `DoSearchAsync`, and made your controller method `async`, so it returns `Task<ActionResult>`.

Comment: Scalability is not an issue. This is kind of what I did in the end (+1 but not accepted as I used Eduardos answer to get here) - but instead of making it async I used Task.WaitAll and then processed the results.  What's the difference between waitall and whenall?

Comment: @Pete, the difference is significant, but that's the subject for a separate question, rather than a comment (I'm sure it was answered before here on SO). Overall, you should avoid blocking with `.Wait()`/`.Result` in ASP.NET code. Check Stephen's blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: it was for the comments really - it was the Task.result thing i was looking for so that I could process the tasks in an array but also get the results from those tasks after I had called the WaitAll, for some reason Microsoft don't show an example of the .results on their site

Comment: @Pete, that's not the difference between `await Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WaitAll`, really. The difference is asynchronous continuation vs. synchronous blocking, if you like to fit it in the comment format.

Comment: @Pete You should change your accepted answer anyway, IMO. Noseratio's is correct and desirable, Eduardo's isn't. Isn't it proper to change the accepted answer to the better one, even though it came later? Especially since a cursory reading of Eduardo's will lead you to a very bad pattern - starting new threads for I/O bound work you can do using asynchronous calls is bad practice, especially now when the alternative is just as easy.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that it will do both of the awaits simultaneously

This is not correct Pete.  The await means that it will pause execution of the current method until such time that the Async method being called completes.  So your 2 searches will not run in Parallel.

For clarification, see [the first line of the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)....

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes.

You should use [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wait for both searches to complete.  As WhenAll supports returning `Task<T>` and both of your Async searches return a `List<SearchResult>` you can combine the results of both searches and await them both in one statement...

```
    var searchProducts = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetProducts(CoreCache.AllProducts));
    var searchBrochure = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetBrochures(CoreCache.AllBrochures));
    var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(new [] { searchProducts, searchBrochure });
    //allResults is List<SearchResult>[]
```

For completeness, its worth noting that allResults will contain 2 result sets.  It does not perform a union on the 2 sets.

A complete working example for LinqPad can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/MrBaldman/linqpad/blob/master/SO-22961890.linq)

Comment: Ah yes this what I ended up using +1 for the extra info about await - that kind of stops the need for multitreading if I await them in a row!

Comment: @Baldy, after you've edited the answer, it became unclear what you're suggesting to do with `allResults`, aster all. Are you suggesting to do `allResults.Wait()`, as in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task factory, then call wait on the resulting task:

```
Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(10000000));
        taskA.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("taskA has completed.");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I did it his way Ie: `Task task = Task<List<SearchResult>>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetBrochures(brochures)); task.wait()`, how would I then get the actual results out of `task`?

Comment: I don't have a compiler with me right now, but from what I've read there should be a Result property: task.Result; but change your declaration to Task<List<SearchResult>> task = Task<List<SearchResult>>.Factory.StartNew(() => { return GetBrochures(brochures); }); or cast to it

Comment: That task.Result has changed everything!  makes things so much simpler as I can just create an array of tasks and then process them after doing a `.WaitAll`.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using one thread, this uses two to do the same work, with additional overhead. One thread being blocked waiting for another thread, is in no way better than simply calling `DoSomeWork` synchronously.

Comment: Of course this code is an ilustration, in a real case there must be more than one task

Answer (score 0):

You can make it wait for the results to finish before displaying the page by making your function NOT be async.

Or if you want async you could move the search functions to be called by an AJAX call triggered when your page is loaded

Comment: Although this will lose parallel processing if it's needed

Comment: Indeed, I've added an alternative

Comment: This completely goes against the multi-threading use in the backend that I am wanting and also would mean that my site search would not work for anyone who had js turned off

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the function to complete. In order to do that, first make it return a task:

```
private async Task DoSearchAsync()
```

then await it:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchText)
{
    SearchHelper helper = new SearchHelper(searchText);
    await helper.DoSearchAsync();

    return View(helper);
}
```

For more information, see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: This expects a task to be returned from DoSearchAsync() though, which it currently doesn't do

Comment: Pete, the await statement unwraps the task for you.  To complete your implementation of the TAP you should return a Task from DoSearchAsync()

Comment: @Pete No changes to the body of DoSearchAsync are required.