# await Task.WhenAll() vs Task.WhenAll().Wait()

Tags: multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a method that produces an array of tasks ([See my previous post about threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961890/c-sharp-how-to-wait-until-all-tasks-are-finished-before-running-code)) and at the end of this method I have the following options:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // done in a method marked with async
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait(); // done in any type of method
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Basically I am wanting to know what the difference between the two `whenall`s are as the first one doesn't seem to wait until tasks are completed where as the second one does, but I'm not wanting to use the second one if it's not asynchronus.

I have included the third option as I understand that this will lock the current thread until all the tasks have completed processing (seemingly synchronously instead of asynchronus) - please correct me if I am wrong about this one

Example function with await:

```
public async void RunSearchAsync()
{
    _tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task<List<SearchResult>> products = SearchProductsAsync(CoreCache.AllProducts);
    Task<List<SearchResult>> brochures = SearchProductsAsync(CoreCache.AllBrochures);

    _tasks.Add(products);
    _tasks.Add(brochures);

    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks.ToArray());
    //code here hit before all _tasks completed but if I take off the async and change the above line to:

    // Task.WhenAll(_tasks.ToArray()).Wait();
    // code here hit after _tasks are completed
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean second option is not async?  The tasks you fire are going to be processed under different threads, Wait and WaitAll impact the main thread.

Comment: @TMcKeown ah ok so I thought the point of await was to wait for all the processes within the whenall to finish running too before it moved onto any code that came after it

Comment: @Pete: "await Task.WhenAll" should work. Ensure you are on .NET 4.5 and have `targetFramework` set to 4.5 in your web.config.

Comment: @Pete: Are you sure that code hit after await Task.WhenAll(_tasks.Toarray()). I tried your sample but it wait till all task complete.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`await` will return to the caller, and resume method execution when the awaited task completes.

`WhenAll` will *create* a task **When All** all the tasks are complete.

`WaitAll` will block the creation thread (main thread) until all the tasks are complete.

Comment: So there should be no difference between await Task.WhenAll and Tasks.WhenAll().Wait()  as both should wait until all the tasks in the whenall have completed (as it will create the new task and then wait till the new task has completed)  yet as per my edit I have different behaviour between them with the latter acting more like a WaitAll

Comment: @TMcKeown `await Task.WhenAll(...);` should wait on the Task returned by WhenAll, why do you say that the returned task is not used by the call to await in the OPs code? I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: I think that was incorrect.  I removed that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` vs `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()`. If execution is in an async context, always try to avoid `.Wait` and `.Result` because those break async paradigm.

Those two blocks the thread, nothing other operation can take it. Maybe it is not a big problem in small apps but if you are working with high demand services that is bad. It could lead to **thread starvation**.

In the other hand `await` waits for the task to be completed in background, but this does not block the thread allowing to Framework/CPU to take it for any other task.